# Android facebook/twitter share button

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

Is there an easy way to share a link from an android program to facebook, and twitter? 
How to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [`ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) Intent.

Comment: anything else? i would like in API way

Comment: Register your app as a twitter/facebook application to use their APIs!