# How can I create "Recommend on Facebook" button in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to create a button in my android app that will post on facebook the standart recommedation post. It their Facebook api for that? Or other way that I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the standard websnippet and display it in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).
And then integrate the WebView wherever you want to show the button.

The problem with this solution is, the browser will launch and prompt the user to log into facebook.

Check out this link:

[Android WebView for Facebook Like Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108088/android-webview-for-facebook-like-button)

**OR**

use the share intent 
[How to add share button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561877/how-to-add-share-button-in-android)

Comment: Can you explain yourseft, websnippet? I prefer to show a standard facebook recommend window.