# facebook share count not increasing if shared from app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, share

I currently have an Android app that allows users to share posts of a Facebook page.

I am successful in sharing these posts to the user's wall and it looks exactly like a regular share 
except for the fact that the original post share count does not increase.

CODE:

```
                        ...
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("message", msg);
                        params.putString("link", permalink);
                        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST);
                        ...
```

where `permalink` is obtained using FQL query from the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table

As mentioned, this looks exacly like a regular share but has no effect on share count...

Is there a way to do a proper share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are not sharing a content, you are posting in user's wall.

I am no expert in Android SDK and I am not sure that this action counts in Facebook share. In WEB version, I would need to use [Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/) to do that.

Looking for other tracks, I have found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561877/how-to-add-share-button-in-android) showing how to create an Intent to user share content. I believe that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this seems like it would require further user interaction ( letting the user pick the app for share ), is there no way to bypass this using the facebook-api?

Comment: Actually, this practice do not follow [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/).  Facebook makes clear that you must `give users choice and control`, `Respect privacy`, `Don't mislead, confuse, defraud, or surprise users` and `Don't spam - encourage authentic communications`. Facebook has also a policy (look at II-15) that says: "You must not use, display, share, or transfer a user's data in a manner inconsistent with your privacy policy, and must not give us information that you independently collect from a user or a user's content without that user's consent."

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with my app, I give full choice and control via a button...

Comment: You cannot bypass user interaction. The user has to see what will be shared in his account.

Comment: So basically I can not have a custom share mechanism? I can see why that would make sense, but it is still annoying... Thanks.

Comment: Basically, yes. In my oppinion, this is cool, because avoids users to share, for example, a hidden porn link that had its title and thumbnail changed by app (yes, this is possible). So, even that app forces user to share, he will have the chance to check some malicious practice. Less spam, less trunk, more relevance. I think it's cool.